# EF core migration failed: System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Cannot load type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.IOperationResultHandler

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I made Entity Framework core migration first time to my average size project (about 100 tables) and now I am trying to do changes to the azure sql db with 'Update-Database' call in package manager console.

I will get this error always:
Exception message:
Stack trace:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Cannot load type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.IOperationResultHandler, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design, Version=1.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.

Server stack trace:
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.MethodCall.ResolveMethod(Boolean bThrowIfNotResolved)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.MethodCall..ctor(SmuggledMethodCallMessage smuggledMsg, ArrayList deserializedArgs)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.DoDispatch(Byte[] reqStmBuff, SmuggledMethodCallMessage smuggledMcm, SmuggledMethodReturnMessage& smuggledMrm)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.DoTransitionDispatchCallback(Object[] args)

Exception rethrown at [0]:
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.IOperationResultHandler.OnError(String type, String message, String stackTrace)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyString, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
at System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
at System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.AppDomainOperationExecutor.Execute(String operationName, Object resultHandler, IDictionary arguments)
at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid4[T0,T1,T2,T3](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.OperationExecutorBase.InvokeOperationImpl(String operationName, IDictionary arguments)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.OperationExecutorBase.UpdateDatabase(String migration, String contextType)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.DatabaseUpdateCommand.Execute()
at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args)
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

I understood that it try to remove this table primary key - there is multiple similar calls before that:

```
migrationBuilder.DropPrimaryKey(name: "pk_usr", table: "usr");
```

What might be my reasons to my problem - thanks for your help!

References what I have there are (all are 1.1.1.0):

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.Design
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design
```

Comment: Have you somehow solved your problem? becasue I am now facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check if [this](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7071) can fix your issue, if not proceed to the below options
[EF Tools 1.1.0-preview4 Unrecognized option '--config' #7071](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7071)

1. Are you trying to update a database which is already created? if so,
   your migrations might be out of sync with you migration database
   snapshot. it you didn't previously create the database tables with
   migration and/or added or removed a column or table without using
   migration, forget using your current migration and create a new
   database.

   2. Some other reason maybe that you are using the entity framework in a
      [class library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#targeting-class-library-projects-is-not-supported), [this doesn't currently work](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5320);
   3. Another reason could be you .Net Core run-time using some packages
      which are not currently referenced due to a possible update, so make sure
      you are using the packages referenced
   4. or could be, [you updated your solution, or your solution used
      updated nuget packages that are not supported by the installed .NET
      Core Runtime. Ckeck that or the Vice versa](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/16/announcing-net-core-1-1/).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using an incompatible version of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`. Ensure you've installed version 1.1.0.